# Title for selected segment in UISegmentedControl disappears when taking a screenshot programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` added to a `UIToolbar`:

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:toolbarFrame];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
toolbar.translucent = YES;
toolbar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.97 green:0.97 blue:0.97 alpha:1.0];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"Last week", @"Last month", @"All time"];
[segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
[toolbar addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

The toolbar is then added to a view controller. When I take a screenshot of the view controller, something weird happens. The title of the selected segment disappears.

The screenshot is being taken using:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Rendered view:
[image]

Screenshot: 
[image]

Where to start looking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've replaced

```
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

With

```
[self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

And now it works as expected. Still don't understand why that happens though.

Note that `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` is iOS 7 only.

Comment: Any one an idea? drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:YES has some other problems for us...

Comment: What problems is `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` causing to you?

Comment: It's sometimes slower

Comment: drawViewHierarchyInRect on iOS8 results in white images

Comment: I tried to replace line as mentioned in answer above, however still i face same issue.  SegmentedControl's text is disappeared in screenshot.