# UISegmentedControll in UINavigationBar weird screenshot iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, screenshot, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` inside a `UINavigationBar` looking like this:

[image]

Here you can see the way it is created in the Storyboard:

[image]

The problem is that when I create a screenshot programmatically, in order to share it, I got the `UISegmentedControl` without the text of the selected tab, like here:

[image]

As far I know it is normal that the status bar does not appear, and also that the Share button is shown as selected, because in fact it is selected while the screenshot is being taken, but have no clue about what is happening with the `UISegmentedControl`, any idea?

PS: I can share the take-screenshot code, but it is pretty straightforward standard code.

**UPDATE**

This is the screenshot code that I am using:

```
- (UIImage*)screenshot
{
    // Create a graphics context with the target size
    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
    CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Iterate over every window from back to front
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
    {
        if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
        {
            // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
            // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            // Center the context around the window's anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
            // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
            // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                                  -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                                  -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

            // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
            [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

            // Restore the context
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        }
    }

    // Retrieve the screenshot image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is a simple project that reproduces the bug: https://github.com/apascual/APSegmentedControlExample

Comment: Have you tried with my updated answer ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using iOS 7?  If so, are you using the new screenShot api's?  If so, have you set afterScreenUpdates to YES?

```
- (UIImage *) getScreenShotForView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);

    // I think this is what was used pre iOS 7.x
    //[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    // iOS 7.x -->
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES]; // Set To YES
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

#### Update

Based on @LeoNatan's comment, you can use your window

```
- (UIImage *) getScreenShotForView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);

    // iOS 7.x -->
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES]; // Set To YES
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have added the screenshot code I am using... Yes, it is iOS 7, but I am not just taking a screenshot of one view, but from the window, so the UINavigationBar and UITabBar are on it too...

Comment: You can call `drawViewHierarchyInRect:` on a window as well.

Comment: @LeoNatan - Good to know, I updated my answer to draw the window like you suggested.

Comment: I did not realised until now that you had updated the answer and it is in fact correct... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Last updated:** You just need to replace

```
[[window layer] renderInContext:context];
```

to

```
[self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES]; // also tried with "inRact:window.bounds";
```

**Note**  -  `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` is only for `iOS 7`.

For more information, also you can take screenshot just using..

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not solving the issue with the UISegmentControl, this is only making the shareButton not being highlighted...

Comment: I tried it even triggering the action of capturing the screenshot when the data is loaded, without intervention of any button, and it keeps happening...

Comment: I will, but I am not using images, so probably it won't fix it... I have added a simple project that reproduces the bug, see my second update.

Comment: @apascua - look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388335/title-for-selected-segment-in-uisegmentedcontrol-disappears-when-taking-a-screen and https://github.com/shinydevelopment/SDScreenshotCapture/issues/1

Comment: Awesome, this is definitely the right answer. Please, edit it so the "Last update" part is more visible. Congratulations and thanks!