# Layer Screenshot not take UISegmentControl selected text

Tags: ios, screenshot, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to take screenshot of UIView using below code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But problem with `UISegmentControl's` selected text. It's only appear in **IOS7**. perfectly work with `<=IOS6.` I've attached screen shot.

**IOS 6 screenshot which is working fine.**

[image]

**But Same code doesn't work with IOS7+.**

[image]

If anybody find either solution or reason for this, please help me.

Comment: I think text color and background color will be same. so its not showing

Comment: No. I'm nothing do any special coloring change for IOS7. It's working fine in IOS 6. see that color which is differ.

Comment: In screenshot it'll not taking ya in coding also ?

Comment: Ya. I'm sure, there's no change in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found solution, but I don't know, how is it working(concept behind this). But assumption is, layer rendering will happen at end of animation. But `drawViewHierarchyInRect:` will render absolute screen which is presenting. My code as below.

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define iOS7_0 @"7.0"

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(iOS7_0))
    [baseView drawViewHierarchyInRect:baseView.frame afterScreenUpdates:YES];
else
    [baseView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I saw reference from [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388335/title-for-selected-segment-in-uisegmentedcontrol-disappears-when-taking-a-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Please can you try this answer :

In this answer i am trying to change the font color of `SegmentController`.

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14], UITextAttributeFont,
                        [UIColor redColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                        nil];
[yoursegmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:dic forState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSDictionary *clickedindex= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
[yoursegmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:clickedindex forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: try this one : UIFont *Boldfont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:Boldfont
                                                           forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
    [segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes
                                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: See my answer. If you've suggestion,please post it as comment.